# Why does a token-pair in CoW Swap say "insufficient Liquidity for this trade"?

Tags: cow-protocol

[image: Insufficient Liquidity for this trade ERROR]

When trying to trade in CoW Swap, certain tokens pairs give "Insufficient Liquidity for this trade" error.

Answer (score 1):

This error appears because solvers cannot estimate the price of such token-pairs correctly. There might two reasons for this:

- At least one of the traded tokens can't be priced. There needs to be sufficient liquidity in major AMMs liquidity pools to *buy at least 1 ETH* with the given token.
- There isn't sufficient liquidity for the actual traded amounts.

As soon as one and/or both of the above point has been resolved, solvers will be able to price the tokens correctly and the error will no longer appear.